# Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found Converage Api

Tags: php, composer-php

Fatal error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in ConvergeApi.php on line 123

Download and installed code from
https://github.com/markroland/converge-api-php

CentOS 7
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Installed composer

right now I am just tring to get the examples working.

The machine is clean, fresh install
I have followed various example and suggestions posted on StackOverflow.
Any ideas.
The full code is in the link above.

Comment: Have you installed composer, than composer is update all file auto generate

Comment: `composer-dump-autoload -o`

Comment: I have updated from php 5.4 to php 7.1

Comment: I have updated from php 5.4 to php 7.1.   ran 'composer dump-autoload -o'    ran example 'ccsales.php' got the following error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in ConvergeApi.php:123 Stack trace: #0 ConvergeApi.php(153): markroland\Converge\ConvergeApi->httpRequest('ccsale', Array) #1 ConvergeApi.php(254): markroland\Converge\ConvergeApi->sendRequest('ccsale', Array) #2 ccsale.php(18): markroland\Converge\ConvergeApi->ccsale(Array) #3 {main} thrown in ConvergeApi.php on line 123"

Comment: The output for "composer dump-autoload -o"  was
Generating optimized autoload files

Comment: What have you tried so far to get this done? Where are you stuck? Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. This should also include the code you are using

Answer (score 1):

You can do following steps to execute your code:

1. Go to your project dir where `composer.json` resides
2. Install the dependencies using `composer install` command

`converge-api-php> composer install`

**composer install command - parses composer.json file & downloads needed dependencies in vendor directory**

1. Now you can see a new directory named `vendor` in your project dir
2. This `vendor` dir contains a file `autoload.php`, We need to include this file in order to autoload any class dependencies (Eg: `GuzzleHttp\Client`)
3. cd into `converge-api-php\examples\ccsale.php` file & require `vendor/autoload.php` file at the top

`// inside examples\ccsale.php
require(__DIR__.'./../vendor/autoload.php');`

Now try to execute `examples\ccsale.php` file.

Additionally, you can also execute your php-unit test cases with following command:

`converge-api-php$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests/ConvergeApiTest.php`

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: That helped and moved me forward. Now, I get ConvergeApi->ccsale Response: Array ( [errorCode] => 4025 [errorName] => Invalid Credentials [errorMessage] => The credentials supplied in the authorization request are invalid. ) .  Is there a problem with my ssl certificate?

Comment: Yes, now the issue is with the credential info passed while creating instance of ConvergeApi

.$PaymentProcessor = new \markroland\Converge\ConvergeApi(

'YOUR_CONVERGE_MERCHANTID',

'YOUR_CONVERGE_USERID',

'YOUR_CONVERGE_PIN',

false

);

Comment: @BrianErickson, please accept the answer if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your composer director and open the CMD command type this line,

for example:-

```
C:\Windows\system32>composer      //first line 

C:\Windows\system32> cd D:\filedir

D:\filedir>composer update    // enter updating  composer
```

Comment: I am using Linux not windows

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that the given commands resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `vendor/autoload.php` :) you commented it.

All you need to do is uncomment the following line:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Which is part of a file located in your examples folder.

Make sure you load it before trying to make any `GuzzleHttpClient`.